# c# can't focus when SetParent user32.dll

Tags: c#, user32

I'm trying to do a HUD for poker,

So the idea is to set `Form` over the poker application ( which is not my application ) and keep the form always over the table even if i move the poker table

[image]

So I get the IntPtr from the table using

```
  [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int EnumWindows(EnumWindowsCallback lpEnumFunc, int lParam);
```

I need a `Form` for each player at the table for display the informations about a player

So I create my Form which I attach to the poker table using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr SetParent(IntPtr hWndChild, IntPtr hWndNewParent);
```

But then when I show the Form I lost the focus ! I just can't click on the poker table or on my main frame. A solution ?

```
    private void displayHudForEachPlayer(IntPtr pokerTable) {


        StringBuilder windowTitle = new StringBuilder(256);
        GetWindowText(pokerTable, windowTitle, windowTitle.Capacity);

        if (windowTitle.ToString().Contains("Real money"))
        {

            HudPlayerView hudPlayer1 = new HudPlayerView();
            //hudPlayer1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

            Console.WriteLine(windowTitle.ToString());

            IntPtr childHandle = hudPlayer1.Handle;

            ParentWndWrapper oParentWnd = new ParentWndWrapper(pokerTable);
            SetParent(childHandle, pokerTable);

            hudPlayer1.SetBounds(0, 0, 100, 50);
            hudPlayer1.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

I tried also with

```
IWin32Window w = Control.FromHandle(pokerTable);
hudPlayer1.ShowDialog(w);
```

instead of SetParent but same result.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `ShowDialog()` which shows a modal window that will stop you from being able to interact with anything else until the modal dialog is closed.

Try using `Form.Show()` and set `TopMost = true` on each of the forms so they don't get covered up when you click on the poker app.

Comment: So obvious ... tkanks.